# CMake fails to add symbol to static lib present in o file

Tags: makefile, cmake, linker, g++

I have a simple project using cmake build system which creates static library which includes my ringbuffer implementation. From make output I can see that `ringbuffer.c.o` file is created with following symbols:

```
00000000000000f8 g     F .text  0000000000000066 ringbuf_put
000000000000015e g     F .text  000000000000008d ringbuf_get
00000000000001eb g     F .text  0000000000000012 ringbuf_full
00000000000001fd g     F .text  0000000000000012 ringbuf_capacity
000000000000020f g     F .text  0000000000000071 ringbuf_size
0000000000000280 g     F .text  000000000000002b ringbuf_clear
```

Although they are undefined in `libbuffer.a` or rather defined multiple times?

```
0000000000000000 l    df *ABS*  0000000000000000 ringbuffer.c
00000000000000f8 g     F .text  0000000000000066 ringbuf_put
000000000000015e g     F .text  000000000000008d ringbuf_get
00000000000001eb g     F .text  0000000000000012 ringbuf_full
00000000000001fd g     F .text  0000000000000012 ringbuf_capacity
000000000000020f g     F .text  0000000000000071 ringbuf_size
0000000000000280 g     F .text  000000000000002b ringbuf_clear
0000000000000000         *UND*  0000000000000000 ringbuf_put
0000000000000000         *UND*  0000000000000000 ringbuf_size
0000000000000000         *UND*  0000000000000000 ringbuf_get
0000000000000000         *UND*  0000000000000000 ringbuf_clear
```

command which was used to link the library:

```
/usr/bin/ar qc ../lib/libbuffer.a CMakeFiles/ringbuf.dir/ringbuffer.c.o 
/usr/bin/ranlib ../lib/libbuffer.a
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Since this is a simple CMake project, can you add your CMake code to your post?

Comment: @squareskittles The project is quite a bit complicated than that. I just simplified it a bit for the purpose of this question

Comment: It's not a make output, rather a `nm` or `objdump`. It also shows that the symbols are defined. Could you share how this second output is generated?

Comment: yeah sorry, my mistake. It is indeed objdump. the first one is objdump on `ringbuffer.c.o`, the second one is `libbiffer.a`